# spark scala querying reserve keyword

Tags: oracle, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to oracle using spark JDBC and writing to hive. Query has a reserved keyword "GROUP" and not able to fetch the records

```
select "GROUP" FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME;

val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc") 
.option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@database.com:2011/db") 
.option("dbtable", "abcd.efgh") 
.option("user", "abcd") 
.option("password", "pqrst") 
.option("dbtable", s"(select "GROUP" FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME)") 
.option("lower Bound",1L) 
.option("upper Bound",100000L) 
.option("numPartitions",100)e
 .option("fetchSize", "1000") 
.load()
```

I am getting this error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing query **`triple quotes`** and use double quotes for **`"GROUP"`** column

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc") 
.option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@database.com:2011/db") 
.option("dbtable", "abcd.efgh") 
.option("user", "abcd") 
.option("password", "pqrst") 
.option("dbtable", s"""(select "GROUP" FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME)""") 
.option("lower Bound",1L) 
.option("upper Bound",100000L) 
.option("numPartitions",100)e
 .option("fetchSize", "1000") 
.load()
```

Comment: .option("dbtable", s"""(select "GROUP" FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME) as st""") and got the below error. Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended                                                                                               Aslo tried with .option("dbtable", s"""(select "GROUP" FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME)""") and got  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long